# Shadow around a section of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, shadow

I have a `UITableView` with 4 sections. Now I want to add a shadow effect to a particular section of table but not the full table. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: yes, did not found a solution yet

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this for Full table Shadow

```
yourView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
```

Try this for Section shadow

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (cell.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIView.tintColor))){
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 12.0
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
            let layer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
            let bounds: CGRect = cell.bounds
            bounds.insetBy(dx: 25.0, dy: 0.0)
            var addLine: Bool = false

            if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == ( tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1) {
                path.addRoundedRect(in: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)

            } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
                path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY), radius: cornerRadius)
                path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))

            } else if indexPath.row == (tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1) {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
                path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY), radius: cornerRadius)
                path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))

            } else {
                path.addRect(bounds)
                addLine = true
            }

            layer.path = path
            layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor

            if addLine {
                let lineLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
                let lineHeight: CGFloat = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
                lineLayer.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + 10.0, y: bounds.size.height - lineHeight, width: bounds.size.width, height: lineHeight)
                lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
                layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
            }

            let testView: UIView = UIView(frame: bounds)
            testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
            testView.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.backgroundView = testView
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i cannot use this solution because i had to show it for a section in UIScrollView not for a full table

Comment: The question is about `UITableView` sections, and this is the answer to "how do you add a shadow to a `UIView`?" Why is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to alter the sections header and footer as well as all cells of the section.

Use `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`, `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for that. Just add a UIView with rgba 0/0/0/0.2 or similar to each view you want to be dark.

Answer (score 0):

You can add image with shadow as background of UITableViewCell. Shadow should be drawn in the image. It is very simple and your application will run faster.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the shadow for the the section you want.
Here is a sample.

First of all we are making some space available for your header

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == mysection)
    {
        // Returns the height you want for the header section. I am giving 20
        return 20; 
    }
}
```

Then the decoration of the header

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == mysection)
    {
        UIView *shadowView  =  [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,20)] autorelease];
        shadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        // Doing the Decoration Part
        shadowView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
        shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;

        return shadowView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Complete it on your side. This one is a basic outline. Happy Coding :)

Comment: the question is about section, not section header only